# How to fix errors such as unexpected indent?

Tags: python, json, random

My code is below.

I receive errors such as `unexpected indent` etc.

How can I fix these errors?

```
def RSD_Function(devNum,file,devProperties):

    for i in range(0,devNum):
        JsonDump={};
        JsonDump["address"]=devProperties[i][14]
        .
        .
        JsonDump["destination"]=devProperties[i][11]
        .
        .
        ConfigDump[i]= JsonDump;
        JsonDump ={}
        print("sim.devices[",i,"].devTrafficChar.address = ",devProperties[i][14],file=file)
        .
        .
        print("sim.devices[",i,"].trafficModel.destination = ",devProperties[i][11],file=file)
        .
        .
if __name__ == "__main__":

for num in NumberofDevice:        
    DirName = "Config_"+str(DeploymentChar[2])+"_"+str(num)
    TotalSenDev = math.ceil(num*DeploymentChar[2])
    TotalMainDev = math.ceil(num * ((1-DeploymentChar[2])/2))
    TotalRecDev = math.ceil(num * ((1-DeploymentChar[2])/2))


    devProperties = num * [None]
    DT = ['BLE_DEV_CONNECTED_SUPPLY'] * int(num * DeploymentChar[0]+1) + ['BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_RECHARGEABLE'] * int(num * DeploymentChar[1]+1) +['BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_NON_RECHARGEABLE'] * int(num * DeploymentChar[2]+1)
    random.shuffle(DT)

    for dep in range(0,NumberofDeploy):
        SensorLoc = numpy.random.uniform(0,30,size=(TotalSenDev,2))
        MainLoc = numpy.random.uniform(0,30,size=(TotalMainDev,2))
        RecLoc = numpy.random.uniform(0,30,size=(TotalRecDev,2))
        print("////////////////////")
        print(SensorLoc)
        print("////////////////////")
        print(MainLoc)
        print("////////////////////")
        print(RecLoc)

        AddressAssignment = [i for i in range(num)]
        random.shuffle(AddressAssignment)
        for i in range(0,num):
            if (i < TotalSenDev):
                devProperties[i]=["Random",
                                  SensorLoc[i][0],                                      #X-Pos
                                  SensorLoc[i][1],                                      #Y-Pos
                                  random.randint(1, rangeZ),                            #Z-Pos
                                  random.randint(rangeTxRx, rangeTxRx),                 #RxTx-Range
                                  ComputeClass[random.randint(0, 2)],                   #Compute Class
                                  MemoryClass[random.randint(0, 2)],                    #Memory Class
                                  'BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_NON_RECHARGEABLE',                  #Energy Source
                                  random.randint(50, 99),                               #Battery Percentage
                                  random.randint(50, 99),                               #Battery Size
                                  ValidFreq[random.randint(0,3)],                       #Period of Packet Tx
                                  AddressAssignment[TotalSenDev + i % (num - TotalSenDev)],                             #Peer Address
                                  random.randint(1, num-1)*1000,                        #No of Packets to be Tx
                                  7,                                                    #Delay for the first packet
                                  AddressAssignment[i]];                                       

                devProperties[i][5] = ComputeClass[random.randint(0, 1)] if devProperties[i][7] == "BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_NON_RECHARGEABLE" else ComputeClass[random.randint(0, 2)]
                devProperties[i][6] = MemoryClass[random.randint(0, 1)] if devProperties[i][7] == "BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_NON_RECHARGEABLE" else MemoryClass[random.randint(0, 2)]
                devProperties[i][8] = 99 if devProperties[i][7] == "BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_NON_RECHARGEABLE" else random.randint(50, 99)
                devProperties[i][9] = BatterySize[ 0 if devProperties[i][7] == "BLE_DEV_BATTRERY_NON_RECHARGEABLE" else 1]
                devProperties[i][13] = 7
elif ........................

........................................................

for traf in range(0,NumberofTrafficModel):

            if not os.path.exists(DirName):
                os.makedirs(DirName)

             AddressAssignment = [i for i in range(num)]

             random.shuffle(AddressAssignment)

                devProperties[i][11]=AddressAssignment[TotalSenDev + i % (num - TotalSenDev)]
```

HERE I want to change destination only for number of each traffic model

```
fileName =DirName+"\\"+str(num)+"_Deployment_"+str(dep)+"_Traf_"+str(traf)+".rsd"
            file = open(fileName,'w+')
            print("sim.depId = ",dep,file=file)
            RSD_Function(num,file,devProperties)
            fileJSON=open(DirName+"\\"+str(num)+"_Deployment_"+str(dep)+"_Traf_"+str(traf)+".json",'w+')
            json.dump(ConfigDump,fileJSON,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
            fileJSON.close()
            file.close()
```

Comment: Please copy in the trace back of the errors

Comment: If you are being told there is an unexpected indent on line nnnn then you need to fix the indentation on line nnnn. Unless and until you get your Python code correctly indented it will never run and the rest of you questions cannot begin to be answered.